# How can I display a web page in an eclipse view

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

Iam making a new view plugin for eclipse and I need it to display a website.
I know there are eclipse views already that does that but I haven't found a way to do it. I know it is very simple using a JFrame or similar but how can I get it to show in an eclipse view?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an SWT `Browser` component, as described at http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet128.java -- you would need to add the Browser to the view's composite parent when the view is created.